# Div used as background not clickable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a popup with a blacked out background. I want the popup to disappear when the background is clicked. Whilst the popup appears, the background does not appear to be clickable with jQuery. Even when I insert an "alert()" into the code, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<div id="blacked_out_background"></div>
<div id="tr_panel">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#blacked_out_background
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#tr_panel
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#blacked_out_background").click(function () {
    $("#blacked_out_background").hide();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your script is executed after DOM is ready? Everything else looks ok for me

Comment: Seems to work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/zwLRY/

Comment: You should use $(this).hide() instead of using the selector

Comment: @Anton this will not fix the problem.

Comment: @antyrat i know, it's a suggestion to improve his code

Comment: Antyrat was right. Thanks

Comment: maybe you can make it hide when you click on anything that is not your popup, like not targeting the outside div only.